# "error": "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'decoded' before initialization

Tags: reactjs

`Auth Middlewares`

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("./catchAsyncErrors");

/// check if user authenticated or not authenticated
exports.isAuthenticatedUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  if (!token) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Login first to access this resource.", 401));
  }

  const decoded = (jwt.verify(
    token,
    process.env.JWT_SECRET
  ).req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id));

  next();
});
```

`User model code`

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const {
  getProducts,
  newProduct,
  getSingleProduct,
  updateProduct,
  deleteProduct,
} = require("../controllers/productController");

const { isAuthenticatedUser } = require("../middlewares/auth");

router.route("/products").get(isAuthenticatedUser, getProducts);

router.route("/admin/product/new").post(newProduct);

router.route("/product/:id").get(isAuthenticatedUser, getSingleProduct);

router.route("/admin/product/:id").put(updateProduct);

router.route("/admin/product/:id").delete(deleteProduct);

module.exports = router;
```

> I am trying to check whether token and JWT_SECRET matched or not before login, but I am facing a problem when executing the code as mentioned in the title.

"success": false,
"error": "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'decoded' before initialization\n    at F:\React Project\ShopIt\backend\middlewares\auth.js:17:36\n

Comment: I think
`const decoded = (jwt.verify(
    token,
    process.env.JWT_SECRET
  ).req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id));`
should be 
`const decoded = jwt.verify(
    token,
    process.env.JWT_SECRET
  ) ;
req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);`

Comment: Thanks, It's working now.....